# iOS complilation and linking libraries

Tags: ios, arm64

It’s possible in a Xcode project with arm64 architecture compile with libs compiled for armv7,armv7s ?

What if the libs are of third and we can’t recompile to arm64?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get updated versions of your libraries that support arm64 in order to build for arm64.

Comment: but not up to me, an integrator still working in Xcode 5, now he want compile in arm64, but they are not versions of some libs in arm64. is not very suitable, especially when the app is the type that does not take advantage of architecture..

Comment: You will not be able to compile for arm64 if your dependencies do not have an arm64 slice. Period.